# How to Properly Dispose of Objects Pass to DllImport method

Tags: c#, interop, dllimport

How does passing an object to unmanaged code affect its garbage collection?  Do I need to do anything explicitly to dispose of the object?

I am setting up an unmanaged serial port and I have to pass a "Device Control Block" (DCB) object across to unmanaged code as part of setting up the port.  Now when I dispose of the port object do I have to do anything else to dispose of the DCB?

Comment: DCB is a struct, not an object.  Nothing disposable about it, it doesn't store any operating system resources.  Just simple values.  Do not help, none is required.  And [borrow](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/microsoft/win32/UnsafeNativeMethods.cs#366), don't write your own.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection is only available for Managed resources. There is a reason for IDisposable patter and `Dispose` method. It is used for disposing unmanaged resources. Something like FileReaders, where OS File handler will be unmanaged code accessible through Managed code for .Net framework. Disposing the FileWriter/Reader would actually release the handle of unmanaged resource.

In your case you don't have to do anything about `DCB`. It appears it is not holding any unmanaged resources. It is just passed to an unmanaged resource.

Comment: Because it is passed to an unmanaged resource, can I assume it will be disposed of when its not longer needed?

Comment: @Jeeve, Is there any unmanaged resource held by DCB ? From your question it appears NOT. If there is no unmanaged resource then there is no need to `Dispose` it, It will simply become out of scope at the end of your method/section.